# Unminified version of the minified JavaScript code snippet

Tags: javascript, minify, unminify

Here is the minified code snippet

```
if (r.rootNode.children && this.treeClear(t),
    s = s || this.options.source)
        "string" == typeof s && e.error("Not implemented");
```

Please let me know if it is the correctly unminified by me?

```
if(r.rootNode.children)
    this.treeClear(t);
    
s = s || this.options.source

if(s)
    if("string" == typeof s)
        e.error("Not implemented");
```

Comment: This is the first time I see a comma in the condition, and it seems legal (although not a good practice). IMHO, your reverse engineering looks correct. Is it because doesn't behave as the minified version?

Comment: Not exactly equivalent. `x = y` attempts to assign `y` to `x` and returns the value that `y` has during the assignment. The value of `x` may be different from `y` after the assignment: it may be a read-only property or an accessor which yields a different value via its getter. Therefore, it really needs to be `if((s = s || this.options.source))` for it to be equivalent.